# Wordpress Admin - Cannot see all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

For some reason, I've pushed a theme via Git to Wordpress and since then (I am not 100% sure if it's because of that) I cannot see all the pages anymore. I can access them on the front-end and get the page code from inspect element, otherwise I can't edit those pages directly from Wordpress.
[image: ALL(72) but only 24items displayed. In screen options I have 100 pages per page. There is no 2nd page]

Comment: Just apply the default Wordpress theme to check the current theme issue.

Comment: Can you please try by activating the default theme and check If it's working, then that will be theme issue. Otherwise some wordpress core files are changed. try to reinstall wordpress

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another admin switched the language and I was only able to view the pages made in that particular language. Silly mistake from my side. Thank you for the answers. I will keep the post opened in case somebody goes through the same thing and oversees this aspect.